# Why is R / RStudio producing an inconsistent regular expression error?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a regular expression in an R script that runs fine if I run the code by ctrl-Enter but that produces the following error if I run the script by clicking Source.  The error produces is:

```
> df <- df %>% 
+   mutate(date = ymd(date_str)) %>% 
+   mutate(bfr = str_match(figure, '(.*?)([\\d]{1,2})([\\"\\-\\+])?(.*?)?(MS|AW|aw|GB|FR|BRZ ..." ... [TRUNCATED] 
Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

The problem line of code and regular expression are:

```
mutate(b = str_match(figure, '(.*?)([\\d]{1,2})([\\+\\-\\"])?(.*?)?(MS|AW|aw|GB|FR|BRZ|ITY|GER|JAP|IRE|\\d\\d\\s?)([A-Za-z\\s]{2})?(\\s?\\d+|[a-zA-Z1234]{3})?')[,2])
```

I check the regular expression in regex101 and it works fine.  I'm using stringr via the tidyverse package.

Can anyone help me figure out what the syntax error is and why the code works if run with ctrl-Enter.

Here is a link to my regex101 test where you can see some sample data.

https://regex101.com/r/okJ0FO/1

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(
  date_str = paste(2020, 1:12, 1, sep="-"),
  figure = c("1930 DE19", "25+ YMSAiDDk", "32 v[MSAi19", "G..25- Y]40Ai 3", 
             ".35\" vtfMSAQ 6", "..33- V40AQ10", ".28+ Y40AQ18", "g'21+ v25AQ19", 
             "19+30 BE 3", "r.34- VQ40BE16", "^=21-40 BE28", "15\" vw25BE23"
  )
)

df %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date_str)) %>% 
  mutate(b = str_match(figure, '(.*?)([\\d]{1,2})([\\+\\-\\"])?(.*?)?(MS|AW|aw|GB|FR|BRZ|ITY|GER|JAP|IRE|\\d\\d\\s?)([A-Za-z\\s]{2})?(\\s?\\d+|[a-zA-Z1234]{3})?')[,2])
```

Comment: @MrFlick I've provided sample data via a link to regex101.

Comment: Linking to external data is discouraged because it can be separated from the question. I've added some to your question itself, but I cannot reproduce the error. The supplied code runs for me whether I do it line by line in RStudio or if I `source()` the file.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm using version 1.40 of stringr

Comment: @MrFlick what version of R are you running?

Comment: I'm running R 4.0.2

Comment: I'm on R-4.0.2 (win10), string-1.4.0, and I get no errors when running code from the third code block. Granted, I have no idea if it's working (are `G..`, `g'`, `r.` and `^=` among the expected outputs?), but no errors.